# URL Rewrite Redirection

Tags: iis, localhost, web-config, url-rewrite-module, virtual-directory

I have configured a website in IIS with a virtual directory. (applicationHost.config file is given below )

```
<application path="/" applicationPool="TestMovieSearch">
    <virtualDirectory path="/moviesearch" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\fullmovielist" />
</application>
```

I am using URLRewrite to redirect user to a specific html page. I have the below webconfig file placed in this path.

Path : C:\inetpub\wwwroot\fullmovielist

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Catch all for movie search redirection">
                    <match url="/" negate="true" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/MovieSearch/action/movies.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I tried the URL http:\localhost\MovieSearch, its properly getting redirected to movies.html page. I just need to know how the web.config file matches with virtual directory and
properly redirect to movies.html page.

Note: I am a newbie to web.config file. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you don’t need a rewrite rule, but you want to know how this rewrite rule works, is that right?

I guess there is also an action folder in your fullmovielist folder, which contains movies.html. (If not, it is the application of the MVC structure you are using.)

[image]

If you want to know how the url matches the rule and rewrites to new one, it is better to use [fail request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).
[image]
`http://localhost/moviesearch`,the part of "/moviesearch" match the "/" and rewrite to `http://localhost/moviesearch/action/movies.html`.

You can know more rules and ways about url rewrite from [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).